# Accessing elements in an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm having problem accessing an element of an array of pointer. I'll try to reduce the class as much as I can. This is part of a header file that handles all type of data in my code, and then there is the source file. A little bit about these classese. All of them are derived from Data class. class2 is derived from class1 and class3 is a collection(array) of class2.

```
class class1
{
  public:
    class1(const char * S ) : Value(v), v(S)   {}
    class1(const class1 &S) : Value(v), v(S.v) {}
    Str &Value;
  private:
    Str v;
};

class class2 : public class1
{
  public:
    class2( const char * N, const char * V) : class1(V), n(N) {}

  protected:
    Str n;
};

class class3;
{
  public:
    class3 (                               ) {datum = 0;}
    class3 (const class3 &D                ) {set(D) ;}
    class3 (const class2 &S                ) {datum = 0; *this+= S;}
    class3 (const char * nm, const char * v) {datum =0; *this+=class2(nm,v);}

    class2 & operator [] = (const char *N);
    Data & operator += (const Data & D);
    operator class2 * () {return datum? *datum : 0}
    operator class2 **() {return datum? datum : 0}

  protected:
    class2 ** datum;
    class3 & set (const class3 &D);
};
```

This is part of the source file.

```
class3 & class3:: set (const class3 &S)
{
  int ents = S.Strs ();  // How many elements in array
  datum = new StrDatum * [ents + 1];

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < ents; i++)
  {
    datum[i] = new StrDatum (*S.datum[i]);
  }
  datum[i] = 0;
  return *this;
} 
Data & class3::Operator += (const Data & D) // Data is the base class for all data-type classes
{
  if (D.Is (class2Dtype)) // dataType enum {class2Dtype = 2; class3Dtype = 3; etc... }
  {
    int ents = this->Strs();
    class 2 ** tmp = new class2 * [ents +1];

    int i;

    for (i=0; i < ents; i++)
    {
      tmp[i] = datum[i];
    }
    tmp[i++] = (class2 *) MakeMe (D); // Create a class2 instance
    tmp[i] = 0;
    delete [] datum;
    datum = tmp;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Ok.  I've already create the array and I'm trying to access it. I'm able to access the first element but when I try to access the second element I get a segmentation fault.

```
// I create an instance of recordScreen where the array of pointer is created.
// This class has a method called GetData which retrieves the array
// In recordScreen.h
//   class2 & GetData(void);

recordScreen recSc; 
recSc.run();          // The array is created

// If want to see the first element value
Str data = ((class2 *)recSc.GetData())[0].Value; // This works fine.

//But when I try:
Str data2 = ((class2 *)recSc.GetData())[1].Value; // Segmentation Fault

// I check how many elements it has.
class3 test = recSc.GetData();
cout << "Elements = " << test.Strs() << endl; // Output = 2
```

Btw, I didn't write any of these classes, but I'm trying to figure out how they work. If there are something else that should I add, please let me know.

Comment: 1. You should use the debugger and step through your code to find the exact source of your segfault.

Comment: 2. Better not use raw pointers or arrays of them. Instead use standard container classes or smart pointers.

Comment: What is with `v` and `Value` in `class1`?

Comment: `class2( const char * N, const char * V) : class1(V), n(N)` - there is no class1 constructor which accepts `const char*`.

Comment: That reference stuff you have in the classes requires you to write the copy constructor and assignment operator. It's a horrible antipattern. Bin it and watch the bugs fall away.

Comment: SergeyA you are right. I forgot to add that constructor in the question. The original header file has 13 different class with a lot of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just found a way to access the array elements. It was much easier than I thought.

```
recordScreen recSc; 
recSc.run();          // The array is created

class2 ** item;
item = recSc.GetData();

cout << item[0]->Value << endl; // First element
cout << item[1]->Value << endl; // Second element
```